# How to improve a select query performance?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, unity-game-engine, query-optimization

I am working on a method that basically takes an array of Color (Unity Type) as parameter and replace all colors contained in a list by another color contained in another color array.
For example you have 3 mask colors (red, blue green), so each green pixel will be replaced by texture 1, each red by texture 2, etc...

My previous method was messy, with a lot of if loops and took around 1,6ms to be performed, which I thought was really bad.

Finally I came up with another method using LINQ which is a lot cleaner, but surprisingly this query takes actually more than 4,5ms to be performed (for a 64x64 array) :

```cs
Color[] newTexture = texture.GetPixels()
    .Select((color, index) => masks.Contains(color) ? textures[Array.IndexOf(masks, color)][index] : color)
    .ToArray();
```

I tried parallelization but it is even worse:

```cs
Color[] newTexture = texture.GetPixels().AsParallel()
    .Select((p, i) => masks.Contains(p) ? textures[Array.IndexOf(masks, p)][i] : p)
    .ToArray();
```

Do you have any idea why this query takes so much time and how I could improve it ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unfortunate truth of LINQ is that it will pretty much **never** be faster than a for loop. It is because unlike languages like C++ and Rust where lambda expressions can be inlined/compiled-away, any time you invoke an `Action` object, or call `MoveNext()` on `IEnumerable<T>` etc. there is a [VTable lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). As such you shouldn't really use it for games, at least not where performance matters.

Aside from the inherent performance problems LINQ suffers from, you are needlessly copying the copy of the pixels and you are looking through the mask array twice.

You mentioned your for loop was messy? Would something like this work better?

```
// GetPixels() already gives you a copy, no need to copy it again
Color[] newTexture = texture.GetPixels();

// Microsoft's compilers make better code for spans than for arrays,
// maybe Mono does too?
Span<Color> textureSpan = newTexture;
Span<Color> maskSpan = masks;

for (int i = 0; i < textureSpan.Length; i++)
{
    // by checking if the index returned from IndexOf is not negative,
    // you can omit Contains()
    int maskIndex = maskSpan.IndexOf(textureSpan[i]);
    // only change the pixels that need to be changed
    if(maskIndex >= 0)
    {
        textureSpan[i] = textures[maskIndex][i];
    }
}

return newTexture;
```

Comment: Span doesn't seem to be implemented in Unity, but using your method with arrays already give a good improvement, around 0,45ms for each texture.
I can forget Linq then...

I will look more closely if there is a way to use Span in Unity, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @Louis Spans should be available in the newest versions of Unity as far as I know. But yeah, if you're not using one of the latest versions, you won't have them.

Comment: @Louis mark answer as correct if it resolved your issue

Comment: @Petrusion btw, sometimes linq can be faster =) BUT at the expense of additional allocations =) I was surprised by this when helped guys from the server team to transform their helper methods into zero-allocation variant =) Anyway, it is completely true that linq is not the best option in most cases in game development.

Comment: @Morion I'd like to see some examples of LINQ being faster than a for loop. LINQ does lots of VTable lookups for each item, the way I understand it that can't be faster than a hardcoded method *that does the same operations*.